# How to make full use of CPU cores with threading in python 2

Tags: python, multithreading

The following code seems to be executed sequentially rather than concurrently.
And it only made use of one CPU core. 
Is there a way to make it use multiple cores or switch content between threads?
(I hope it could work like Thread class in java.)

```
import threading 

def work(s) :
    for i in range(100) :
        print s
        for j in range (12345678) :
            pass

a = []
for i in range(3) :
    thd = threading.Thread(target = work('#'+str(i)))
    a.append(thd)

for k in a : k.start()
for k in a : k.join()

print "Ended."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads cannot utilize multiple cores in Python. Processes however can.

> multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an
>   API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package
>   offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping
>   the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.
>   Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully
>   leverage multiple processors on a given machine. It runs on both Unix
>   and Windows.

Click [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine asked me this once. In your case, just use [`multiprocessing.process`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions) and that will use all your cores.